# Syntax combining partial query into one

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a new query based on another.

Example:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `field2` > 0 AND (`field3` LIKE '%".$keyword%."%' OR `field4` LIKE '%".$keyword."%' ** insert new parameters from another query here **  ) AND `field5` <= 0\"';
```

I tried below and didn't work. Wonder if I am getting it right.

```
   $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `field` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
    $new_query = '\"SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `field2` > 0 AND (`field3` LIKE \'%\".$keyword%.\"%\' OR `field4` LIKE \'%\".$keyword.\"%\'';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $keyword2 = $row['something'];
        $new_query .= " OR `field2` LIKE '%" . $keyword2 . "%' OR `field4 LIKE '%" . $keyword2 . "%'";
    }
    $new_query .= ') AND `field5` <= 0\"';
}

if ($result = $con->query($new_query)){
    .........etc
}
```

Appreciate if someone can help!!

Comment: I think your quoting is all wrong. var_dump ($new_query) to see what you've created. It will contain literal $keyword, not a substituted variable.

Comment: I have tried to remove the backslash but it breaks my php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$new_query = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE field2 > 0 AND (field3 LIKE '%$keyword%' OR field4 LIKE '%$keyword%' ";
...
$new_query .= " OR `field2` LIKE '%$keyword2%' OR `field4 LIKE '%$keyword2%'";
...
$new_query .= ') AND `field5` <= 0';
var_dump($new_query); // have a look at the query you have created
```

Comment: Thanks and now I know I shouldn't use the dot before/after the variables. I will update my question with solution later today! thanks and it works great :)